# Symmetric Operator vs. Real Spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

> For symmetric operators one has a characterization:
>   $$A\text{ symmetric}:\quad A=A^*\iff\sigma(A)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$$
>   *(I want to investigate to what extend symmetry is a necessary assumption.)*

On the one hand not every symmetric operator has real spectrum:
$$A\text{ symmetric}\nRightarrow\sigma(A)\text{ real}$$
*(In fact this is true only for the self adjoint ones.)*

Does the converse fail as well, that is, not every operator with real spectrum is symmetric:
$$A\text{ symmetric}\nLeftarrow\sigma(A)\text{ real}$$

Comment: Every self adjoint operator *is* symmetric

Comment: Consider $A=[1 i;0 0]$. The set of eigenvalues is real but $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: @Any: Thx ;) do u mind putting this as answer?

Comment: This is a curious related fact, but different than what you're asking. Suppose $H$ is a complex Hilbert space and $S : \mathcal{D}(S)\subset H\rightarrow H$ is linear and symmetric. If $S\pm iI$ are surjective, then $S$ is a closed densely-defined selfadjoint operator. It is enough to assume that $S-\lambda I$ is surjective for some $\lambda$ in the open upper half-plane and for some $\lambda$ in the open lower half-plane.

Comment: Yes thats just the basic criterion on self adjointness ;) Btw good morning T.A.E.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example 1:** Take any bounded selfadjoint $A$, and any continuously invertible linear $P$, and form $B=P^{-1}AP$. Then $(B-\lambda I)=P^{-1}(A-\lambda I)P$ gives real spectrum for $B$ because $(B-\lambda I)$ is invertible iff $(A-\lambda I)$ is invertible and, in that case, $(B-\lambda I)^{-1}=P^{-1}(A-\lambda I)^{-1}P$. However, $B^{\star}=P^{\star}A(P^{\star})^{-1}$ may not be selfajdoint, even though the spectrum of $B$ is the same as that of $A$.

**Example 2:** If $A$ is a matrix which is diagonalizable with all real eigenvalues, but which does not have an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, then $A$ is not selfadjoint.
A matrix $A$ is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial $m(\lambda)$ has no repeated factors. The eigenvectors for different eigenvalues are mutually orthogonal iff $A$ is unitarily equivalent to a diagonal matrix. Otherwise, $A$ is just similar to a diagonal matrix and may not be selfadjoint.

**Example 3:** The spectrum of a nilpotent $A$ is $\{0\}$. However, no non-zero nilpotent $A$ can be selfadjoint because $A^{n}=0$ for a normal $A$ implies $A=0$.

Comment: I don't quite understand the first example - why is the spectrum real then? Besides, being diagonalizable is equivalent to possessing an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, isn't it?! Or did you mean being unitary equivalent to a multiplication operator?

Comment: $(B-\lambda I)^{-1}$ exists iff $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ exists and, in that case, $(B-\lambda I)^{-1}=P^{-1}(A-\lambda I)^{-1}P$. So, if $A$ is selfadjoint, then $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)$ is contained on the real line. (To avoid domain issues, I'm assuming $A$ is bounded.) This works for any invertible $P$. If $P$ is unitary, then $B$ will be selfadjoint, but not otherwise, at least not in general. For example 2--any set of independent vectors can serve as eigenvectors of a diagonalizable matrix, without being orthogonal.

Comment: I added the new detail to the post.

Comment: Ah right good to know I forgot about the similarity transformations long time ago...

Answer (score 2):

*Since Any seemed to disappear let me post his comment as answer...*

Consider a nonsymmetric matrix with positive eigenvalues:
$$A:=\pmatrix{0&1 \\0&0}:\quad \langle A e_1,e_2\rangle\neq\langle e_1,Ae_2\rangle\quad(\sigma(A)\subseteq\mathbb{R})$$